# Mock function A called within B when A is defined within the same file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I have a file (`example.js`) that looks like this and I'd like to test it.

```
function alpha () {
  return 'alpha'
}

function beta () {
  return alpha() + ' ' + 'beta'
}
```

Here's an example of the test for that file:

```
const test = require('ava')
const {beta} = require('./example')

test(t => {
  t.is(beta(), 'alpha beta')
})
```

I'm interested in having mocking the use of `alpha` within `beta`, when `beta` is defined within `example.js`. I know things that mock the `require` call so that dependencies could be mocked, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to do it this way. Using require creates an enclosure where anything not exported is unavailable outside of its scope. I think rather you need something that concatenates the code without the use of require or import and won't create that enclosure. If you're using nodejs then grunt and grunt-contrib-concat can do that.